# My iOS 8.0 application is not rotating, and I have no idea why. How can I debug device rotation?

Tags: ios, screen-rotation

I'm building an app whose interface has always rotated just fine when the device is rotated fine, but now does not rotate at all.

Strangest thing is, the app rotates just fine when run in the simulator. This says to me that there is absolutely nothing wrong with my application code.

My project settings clearly state that all orientations are supported:

[image: screenie]

What could be the problem here? What should I do to find out what had changed since the last time it's worked and rotated? Thanks.

EDIT: in response to comments, yes, I'm sure that the device's orientation is NOT locked (i.e. from the command pane), and that hardware switch doesn't have anything to do with orientation.  Springboard and other apps rotate just fine.

Comment: have you specified anything in your ViewControllers for `supportedInterfaceOrientations`?

Comment: You sure the device isn't locked? Do other application rotate?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have updated my question with responses to your queries.

Comment: Wow, this is strange. I have just run a development build of my app again with no changes, and it works.

Comment: Probably Xcode’s famous *clean, probably delete derived data, and it magically works!*

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this:

For iOS 2.0 - 7.1.2, use the following UIView delegate method:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // Print a message to the screen to make sure its being called
    NSLog(@"Trying to rotate...");
}
```

For iOS 8 and above:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{   
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    {
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

        // Write to log
        NSLog(@"Trying to change view...");

    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    { 

    }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

This should help to see if the device is attempting to rotate...